# Math expressions to MathML

Tags: c#, math, expression, mathml

I am trying to build functionality as on [this site](http://www.mathmlcentral.com/Tools/ToMathML.jsp) where a user will enter a math expression in the text area and it will be rendered as MathML format.

Example:

```
Input expression string: cos(x^3)

Then the expression should be converted to MathML as:

<math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'>
    <mrow>
        <mi>cos</mi>
        <mo>&#8289;</mo>
        <mo>(</mo>
        <msup>
            <mi>x</mi>
            <mn>3</mn>
        </msup>
        <mo>)</mo>
    </mrow>
</math>
```

What is a C# solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a basic expression to MathML parser from a parser I had since earlier. You can download or fork the [result here at BitBucket](https://bitbucket-archive.softwareheritage.org/projects/re/relling/expressiontomathml.html). (download link to the left).

Use the `ToMathML(expression)` method of the `Parser` class to convert the expression to MathML.

It also comes with a command line test program for testing the parser, the command for generating MathML is ml:

```
calc ~:> ml cos(x^3)
<math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'><mrow><mi>cos</mi><mrow><mrow><mo>(</mo><mrow><msup><mi>x</mi><mn>3</mn></msup></mrow><mo>)</mo></mrow></mrow></mrow></math>
calc ~:> ml 1/(x-1)
<math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'><mrow><mfrac><mn>1</mn><mrow><mrow><mo>(</mo><mrow><mi>x</mi><mo>-</mo><mn>1</mn></mrow><mo>)</mo></mrow></mrow></mfrac></mrow></math>
calc ~:>
```

There is no implied multiplication in the parser so you have to always use * in expressions (like 2*x).

Hopefully it is useful for your scenario. I guess it depends on how full featured you need it to be. In it's current form the parser will convert the expression to a pretty basic subset of MathML.

Feel free to fork it and continue working on it.